# Why can a non-static derived class method be called from a casted pointer to an instantiated base class object?

Tags: c++, pointers, casting

I don't understand why the following code sample works and would like some clarification. It seems to me that since `derivedMethod` is a non-static method of `Derived`, it should only be callable from an instantiated `Derived` object (or a pointer to one). However, by casting a pointer to an instantiated `Base` object to a pointer-to-`Derived`, `derivedMethod` can be called. Why?

**Code:**

```
// compiled with gcc
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base 
{ 
    void derivedMethod() { cout << "foo" << endl; } 
};

int main()
{
    Base *basePtr = new Base();
    ((Derived *)basePtr)->derivedMethod();
    delete basePtr;

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
foo
```

**Edit:**

Before posting this question, I modified `Derived` to include an integer member, which I then output in `derivedMethod`. It still compiled and ran without any errors.

**Edit:**

I realize that this is not good C++ coding style. This is just a question regarding why the code sample I provided works, since it mimics code I found in the wild.

Comment: Undefined behaviour is undefined and it can get weird :)

Comment: @dreamlax, Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried that and it compiled and ran without any errors.

Comment: @Sam Yes, that's the tricky thing about **UB**: The compiler leaves you behind in the woods somewhere ;-) ...

Comment: It's UNDEFINED BEHAVIOUR - it can, and often will, do things that aren't meaningful. It won't necessarily crash, cause an error. But just as much, it may well cause a crash, unexpected changes to something else, etc, etc. It's undefined, nobody says what it should do, it's up to the compiler writer to "make it do something".

Comment: C-style casts like `(Derived *)basePtr)` (for whatever) usually aren't a good idea for proper c++ code ...

Comment: Downvoter: please explain what is wrong with my question.

Comment: @Sam _'Downvoter ..'_ **C-style casts ...** in combination with hitting UB! There's tons of explanations, why this is prone to be going wrong!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ So the downvote is for using C-style casts? I asked the question because I found something like this in code someone else wrote... which is actually for low-level performance-critical code. I just don't see how the use of C-style casts should have anything to do with the quality of the question in relation to the code sample I provided. EDIT: This is in response to your original unedited comment: "C-style casts ...".

Comment: @Sam It obviously doesn't work as you intend, does it?

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that people downvote questions for all manner of reasons. I believe in this case, it's more because "you could have searched the site and found some sort of information about this". But, in my experience, it is entirely meaningless to even attempt to understand the logic behind downvotes of both answers and questions. For example, someone downvoted my answer, for some reason.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I actually did do a fair amount (about 15 minutes) of searching around SO before posting the question to give a good effort to not post a duplicate. I understand and appreciate the high standards of the website, which I have been reading for many years... I have only just started posting on it myself for fear of being shot down needlessly. By the way, thank you for your high-quality answer.

Comment: @Sam OK, for what should I nag (@Mats I didn't downvote of course!) ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I believe you failed to understand the question, which asked, "why *can*", not "why *does*"? It *can* work. I was not assuming that it *does* work all the time. I was actually surprised that it worked at all.

Comment: @Sam _' believe you failed to understand the question'_ I'm understanding pretty well! You don't really want to start bothering about ;) ...

Comment: OK, chill pill taken. :)

Comment: @Sam Good so!! Slàinte!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially lying to the compiler by saying "Make this a `Derived *`" when you use the cast. Since the compiler is then obliged to do what you have asked for [and there are certainly cases, with more complex code, where you may indeed WANT to do this, because you know that the pointer is indeed a pointer to `Derived`, just that currently you have only a `Base *` pointer].

The "correct" way to do this, however, is to use `dynamic_cast<Derived *>(basePtr)`, which will return NULL if the conversion didn't work. So something like this:

```
Derived *dPtr = dynamic_cast<Derived *>(basePtr);
if (dPtr != NULL)
{
   dPtr->derivedMethod();
}
```

Now, this is safe, because if `basePtr` isn't pointing to a valid `Derived` class, the result will be `NULL`, and not go into the code that calls `derivedMethod`.

Note also that as it stands, there is no guarantee at all what actually happens when you call `derivedMethod` in your code. It may crash, or it may "work". (And in this simple example, the compiler may even detec the case and give an error - but it doesn't have to, and this is because in more complex cases, the compiler won't be able to detect it anyway).

Also, using member variables in `Derived` may or may not cause detectable problems. It all depends on exactly what is "after" the `Base` object returned by `new Base()` - it may be "unused space" there (in which case everything "works as expected" [as if you had actually allocated extra space for a `Derived` object - but of course the value is not initialized, so don't do this with for example `std::string` which requires construction before it can be safely used], or it may be something important, so if you write to that location, things go horribly wrong (e.g. `delete basePtr` crashes because your code overwrote something that `delete` needs). But we're talking undefined behaviour, and the compiler/runtime system is allowed to do almost anything here, and "nothing" is technically wrong, no matter how bizarre. If the code decides to print pi with 1000 decimals, play music, or crash. And both C and C++ have a large number of situations where the specification says "what happens in this case is undefined". This is largely because it could be hard/expensive [1] to detect the situation and do something "meaningful".

Note that this will perhaps "not work":

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct Base { };
struct Derived : Base { int y; void derivedMethod() { cout << "foo" << endl; y = 77; } };

int main()
{
    Base b;
    int x;
    Base *basePtr = &b;
    x = 42;
    ((Derived *)basePtr)->derivedMethod();

    cout << "x=" << x << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Now, it's POSSIBLE that it shows `x = 77` here. It's also possible it doesn't. Depends on exactly what the compiler does.

[1] Say for example, that in some processors the compiler would have to add 50 extra instructions to check for an error. On another processor it's one extra instruction, so not bad. But the company that produces the first processor that need 50 extra instructions to check something will definitely not want this error to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

Because in this moment you have a `Derived*` pointer. How should the compiler know that you dont have? If you want to check whether this is really the case at runtime you have to use a `dynamic_cast`. If you reinterpret cast your `Base*` to a `Derived*` though  like in the snippet you get **Undefned Behavior** and the program will likely crash if `derivedMethod` access any members of `Derived`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I meant the only question I asked and the only one I edited: "Why can a non-static derived class method be called from a casted pointer to an instantiated base class object?".

Answer (score 0):

Class methods are stored independent of the instantiated objects, and interaction with an object is actually just interaction with the interface that the object implements. So calling a class method doesn't interact with the instantiation of a class until it needs to access some stored data within the class (a property).

By casting a Base class pointer to the Derived class pointer it now assumes that the object referenced implements the Derived class interface and is perfectly happy calling Derived class methods referencing the Base class object.

However, as others have stated, this leads to undefined behavior. As the Base class does not implement the interface of the Derived class it is possible to assume data exists where it, in fact, does not. In your example, the two objects, even when instantiated, are technically abstract since there is no data associated with them. If they each had different properties it is possible that a method would reference the wrong property or completely unassociated memory.

Comment: This is of course dependant on the implementation of the compiler. I agree that all known compilers do indeed work this way, but it's not stipulated by the C++ standard that it HAS to be this way. One could store the code for the methods inside the object, for example. But it would be a lot of wasted space in many cases... ;)

Comment: @MatsPetersson There's a chance one even specifies hard-wired function call entries like `virtual void foo() = 0x00000042;` and bind some function body definton!